# My if statement doesnt seem to be accepted

Tags: c#, console, console-application

```
if(string s; s = Console.ReadLine(); s == "ja" || "Ja")
```

[A screenshot of all the errors i got from that single line
I dont understand a single of them](http://gyazo.com/ffbd61ebab72b85c8c6af09b0cce5615) 
Can somebody explain

Comment: Move `string s; s = Console.ReadLine();` outside of the if.

Comment: C# has grammar rules that define what operations can appear inside an `if`, and also type rules that define what objects can be used with certain operators.  You've ignored all of the rules.

Comment: [study!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable inside of `if` statement, and this is also invalid: `s == "ja" || "Ja"` you need to separate each condition like this:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
if(s == "ja" || s == "Ja")
```

Or you can just use:

```
if(s.ToLower() == "ja")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s; 
s = Console.ReadLine();
if(s == "ja" || s== "Ja")
{    

}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid C# syntax.  Inside `if` statement there should be an evaluation that results in a boolean value.  Can't declare new variables inside, nor `s == "ja" || "Ja"` makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow that sort of thing. Try something like the following:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine() ;

bool isEndOfFile = s == null ; // Console.ReadLine() returns null at end-of-file
if ( isEndOfFile ) throw new Exception( "That was unexpected!" ) ;

bool isYes = !isEndOfFile && s.Trim().Equals( "Ja" , StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) ;
if ( isYes )
{
  HandleYesInput() ;
}
```

In general, keep things simple. *Intentional programming* will help you: work in a declarative manner to express your intent using small discrete methods and local variables as flags for each of the conditions you're testing, rather than trying to do everything in one complicated expression. You could do something like this:

```
string s = null ;
if ( (s=Console.ReadLine()) && s != null && s.Trim().Equals("Ja",StringComparison.CurrentCulture.IgnoreCase) )
{
  ...
}
```

You gain a little brevity at the expense of readability, traceability and debugability. When your code doesn't work as expected, which version do you think will be easier to understand or to diagnose and fix? That goes triple, if the person who's assigned the task of fixing the problem doesn't understand the code or what it's trying to accomplish and has to get up to speed quickly.

And that person might well be you, looking at code your wrote 5 years earlier.